# gitlab Push Rejected by remote

Tags: gitlab, push

I'm trying to update my Android Project and my J2EE project on [gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/) but I get this error when I try to push:

```
Push rejected: Push new_branch to origin/new_branch was rejected by remote
```

[image]
I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40142180/android-studio-git-push-rejected) and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620253/git-push-rejected) but the problem is still there.

Help me please.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have permissions on that repository. Also make sure the branch you're trying to push isn't protected in the reporitory settings.

Comment: Thanks this helped me! The master branch is protected by default i assume, and only the maintainer can push to it, developers can't

Comment: Yes, master is protected by default. If oyu want to make changes to master, make another branch and open a Merge Request into master.