# Pushing to a remote empty repository on bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am getting the following error on pushing the local git repo to empty remote repo. It's a private repo.

> $ git push origin master
>   To https://bitbucket.org/lord_of_codes/uat_api.git
>    ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
>   error: failed to push some refs to 'https://lord_of_codes@bitbucket.org/lord_of_codes/uat_api.git'
>   hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
>   hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
>   hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
>   hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

I just created a empty git repo on bit bucket. 
I did `git init` in my local project
I did `git add .`
I commit for first `git commit -m "Initial Commit"`
I did `git config --global user.name` `git config --global user.email`
I did `git remote add origin url`
I did `git push origin master`
Then I got that error. 
I also tried pushing codes before commit, and also tried `git pull`. But It's not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51997262/7254873 let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a **non-fast-forward** error. Github has a small section explaining this, check it out [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/dealing-with-non-fast-forward-errors).

Basically what `git`'s doing is preventing you from writing into a repo whose head it different from yours. It means your repo (https://bitbucket.org/lord_of_codes/uat_api.git) has commits that are different from the one in your PC/local code and you're trying to *add* more commits/changes to a codebase which is different from yours.

According to GitHub you can fix this by fetching and merging the changes made on the remote branch with the changes that you have made locally:

```
    $ git fetch origin
    # Fetches updates made to an online repository
    $ git merge origin YOUR_BRANCH_NAME
    # Merges updates made online with your local work
```

Or, you can simply use git pull to perform both commands at once:

```
    $ git pull origin YOUR_BRANCH_NAME
    # Grabs online updates and merges them with your local work
```

> In other cases, this error is a result of destructive changes made locally by using commands like `git commit --amend` or `git rebase`.
>   While you can override the remote by adding `--force` to the `push` command, you should only do so if you are absolutely certain this is what you want to do. 
>   [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4684404/5698740)

For more understanding on git refer to this amazing "[A Visual Git Guide](https://marklodato.github.io/visual-git-guide/index-en.html#merge)"

Answer (score 1):

You can push forcefully to the remote branch which will solve the issue.

```
git push -u origin master # without --force
```

if that does not work, since it's an empty repository created by you, you can do

```
git push -u -f origin master # with force
```

Comment: What if the data in `remote` is important? You should mention the consequences of a `--force`.

Comment: If the remote is important, there is always a way to resolve such issues. Either by pulls with conflict resolutions or allowing unrelated histories along the way depending on the situation but in this case, the remote is empty. which is fine but the --force will erase histories.

Comment: Remote is not empty! I think you already knew that. This might be a new git user and he/she might not know how git works. Consider a repo used by people other than OP, if OP just copy-pasted your answer the team's previous commit history would be lost.

Comment: I knew remote is empty from the question. The user created the repo and that is a fresh one.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem:

```sh
(! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@it-bucket:some-project/some-repo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.)
```

when i am pushing my local repository to the remote repository.

**Problem**: I was creating the new repository on git-bucket and I initialized with README file which actually doesn't match with my local repository.

**Solution**: I delete the existing repository OR create a new repository and **doesn't** initialize with README file then add the following commands

```sh
git remote add origin "repository URL"
```

and then

```sh
git push -u origin master
```